# use conditionals to change column in R

Tags: r

I have to create a new column using a bunch of conditional language, and I believe I've run into a roadblock where I'm way overcomplicating it. So hoping to come here for a little help.

I have a dataset of events grouped by ID number. These are recurrent events (multiple observations for  one ID number). The start time corresponds to the stop time of the previous event. I need to eliminate a series of observations (those where d = 0 and event = 1), and stitch the start and stop times together in the remaining events (those where d == 1 or event == 0) to represent a straight flow of time.

Just to be clear here: event is the presence of a diarrheal episode and d is the presence of a specific virus being tested for during that episode. Observations where event = 0 represent censoring at 1095 days. I need to stitch together the episodes of virus and the final observation representing censoring. Meaning, I need every instance where that virus pops up in testing (d == 1) and also every episode where event = 0. And then every other episode needs to be rendered NA in these new start- and stop-time variables of interest.

I want it to go from this:

```
idnum  d  event   age_start   age_end   
A      1    1        0          165
A      0    1       165         396
A      0    1       396         525
A      1    1       525         576 
A      1    1       576         786
A      0    1       786         925
A      0    0       925         1095
B      0    1       0           123
B      0    1       123         366
B      1    0       366         625
B      0    1       625         703
B      1    0       703         825
B      0    1       825         1023
B      0    0       1023        1095
C      0    1       0           95
C      0    1       95          485 
C      0    1       485         900
C      0    0       900         1095
```

to this:

```
idnum  d  event   age_start   age_end
A      1    1       0           165
A      0    1       NA          NA
A      0    1       NA          NA
A      1    1       165         576 
A      1    1       576         786
A      0    1       NA          NA
A      0    0       786         1095
B      0    1       NA          NA
B      0    1       NA          NA
B      1    0       0           625
B      0    1       NA          NA
B      1    0       625         825
B      0    1       NA          NA 
B      0    0       825         1095
C      0    1       NA          NA
C      0    1       NA          NA  
C      0    1       NA          NA
C      0    0       0           1095
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've hit a wall.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided what the output should look like given this input. Thanks!

Comment: provided output!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
# Add row numbers to help with a join below
my_data <- my_data %>% mutate(row = row_number())

left_join(
  # join a simplified version of my_data that doesn't have age cols...
  my_data %>% select(row, idnum:event),

  # ... with a version that only exists when d==0 and/or event==1,
  #   with age_start using the prior age_end within each idnum
  my_data %>%
    filter(!(d==0 & event == 1)) %>%
    group_by(idnum) %>%
    mutate(age_start = lag(age_end, default = 0)) %>%
    ungroup()
)

Joining, by = c("row", "idnum", "d", "event")
# A tibble: 18 x 6
     row idnum     d event age_start age_end
   <int> <chr> <int> <int>     <dbl>   <int>
 1     1 A         1     1         0     165
 2     2 A         0     1        NA      NA
 3     3 A         0     1        NA      NA
 4     4 A         1     1       165     576
 5     5 A         1     1       576     786
 6     6 A         0     1        NA      NA
 7     7 A         0     0       786    1095
 8     8 B         0     1        NA      NA
 9     9 B         0     1        NA      NA
10    10 B         1     0         0     625
11    11 B         0     1        NA      NA
12    12 B         1     0       625     825
13    13 B         0     1        NA      NA
14    14 B         0     0       825    1095
15    15 C         0     1        NA      NA
16    16 C         0     1        NA      NA
17    17 C         0     1        NA      NA
18    18 C         0     0         0    1095
```

Comment: I made some edits when I noticed mistakes earlier -- does it not work with this current version?

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much! One day I want to be this good at coding.

Answer (score 1):

Change `age_start` and `age_end` columns to `NA` when `d = 0 & event = 1`. Fill those `NA` values with the previous non-NA value, update `age_start` value with the previous `age_end` value. Change the 1st value in `age_start` to 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(age_start:age_end, ~replace(., d == 0 & event == 1, NA))) %>%
  group_by(idnum) %>%
  tidyr::fill(age_start, age_end) %>%
  mutate(age_start = lag(age_end)) %>%
  mutate(across(age_start:age_end, ~replace(., d == 0 & event == 1, NA)), 
         age_start = replace(age_start, which.max(!is.na(age_end)), 0)) %>%
  ungroup

#   idnum     d event age_start age_end
#   <chr> <int> <int>     <dbl>   <int>
# 1 A         1     1         0     165
# 2 A         0     1        NA      NA
# 3 A         0     1        NA      NA
# 4 A         1     1       165     576
# 5 A         1     1       576     786
# 6 A         0     1        NA      NA
# 7 A         0     0       786    1095
# 8 B         0     1        NA      NA
# 9 B         0     1        NA      NA
#10 B         1     0         0     625
#11 B         0     1        NA      NA
#12 B         1     0       625     825
#13 B         0     1        NA      NA
#14 B         0     0       825    1095
#15 C         0     1        NA      NA
#16 C         0     1        NA      NA
#17 C         0     1        NA      NA
#18 C         0     0         0    1095
```

Comment: Finally learned how lag works from this post